# How do I run .ASP (ASP Classic) pages locally (on my development PC) for testing, etc.?

Tags: windows, asp-classic

I'm working on some old .asp pages. I mostly do VB development so I'm a newbie to .ASP.

How can I run those pages locally for testing?

I'm running Windows XP Home SP2.

I'm guessing I'll need to install a local server, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you will need a local server. However, IIS doesn't install on XP Home. But like most things, there are workarounds.

[Installing IIS on XP home](http://adamv.com/dev/articles/iis-on-xp-home/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need IIS installed locally to test ASP.  IIS is part of XP Pro but not of XP Home.

So officially you will need to upgrade at least to Pro.

Answer (score 0):

There are also some other servers out there ranging from free to not that let you test your ASP code. I've heard of, but not used, Baby Web Server: http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_web_server.html